# Multiple mysql queries for building dashboard

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-4, dashboard

I'm developing a PHP dashboard with statistics from a lot of different MySql tables. There is need for many cumulatives and other totals for building charts etcetera. Some queries can be very simple, others join and compare many tables at once.

To do this properly I am considering 3 approaches;

1) Creating a master table which is constantly updated after each front-end (website) and back-end (CRM) interaction and contains only totals for different purposes. So the data is easily accessible with a simple select statement for building the main dashboard.

2) Using many and/or complex queries each time the dashboard is generated. This will take less developing time but more loading time. Maybe there is a better way to manage the order and execution of each query.

3) Creating cron jobs for updating the totals in the background. This is my least favourite approach because is feels outdated for multiple reasons.

Could someone advise me and explain what the best approach would be for the long term?

Thanks in advance.

Fred.

Comment: Have you considered MySQL Workbench?  It is free download and no fees and has dashboard displays built in.

Comment: Hi Wilson. Thanks for the tip. I will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st of all there is no "correct approach", but only one that would fit your needs
In fitting your needs 2 things must be considered:

1. Your business requirement (real time, daily updated etc)
2. Scalability of the code maintenance

As per your case, I would combine the options.
1st of all, I would create a dedicated database with dedicated db, which is good for performance, and historical data saving (which might change, if you take your 2nd approach)

Under that condition, the question whether to update the dashboard online or via a cron job: very dependent on the business need. I think a cron job is better
1st of all, in's scalable - you can ditch it in the future, and update only the dashboard...
2nd of all, you can time it to run during "slow hours" preventing overloading your production servers. Different cron jobs can update different tables in a different frequency etc.

This is of course, my opinion. Hop it helps

Comment: Hi Guy. Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. I think that you are right. Most of the data for the primary dashboard can be updated daily with cron jobs during slow hours. And a dedicated db for historical data would be the way to go. Thanks again.